# Why am I unable to make a QMenu invisible?

Tags: qt

I added a QMenu with the designer to my QMainWindow for actions that are only for debugging and tests. I want to simply make it invisible for a realese compilation.

However when I call:

```
ui->menuTests->setVisible(false);
```

Nothing happens? How do I make that menu not visible without removing it from my application? (I can disable it, but that is horrible....)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set visible/unvisible for the action, not for QMenu:

```
ui->menuTests->menuAction()->setVisible(false);
```